# How are windows created with c++?

Tags: c++, window, static-libraries

I'm new to C++.  I have a question about creating Windows (Frames) for programs through the use of the Command-line (cl, exe) with regular Notepad.  Perhaps it's a too advanced for me to ask at my stage, but I would still like to know for future use.

Does anyone know of which Libraries are needed and the Code to be used with them/it?  I have created a small program, and would like to be displayed in a Window.  Thanks.

Comment: Learn the Windows API. Come back in six months when you're done. (Unless you're talking about Windows 8, in which case you need C++/CX.)

Comment: The standard reference used to be the book "Programming Windows" by Charles Petzold. However, when you're done learning, maybe nobody uses Windows anymore. Maybe you can skip Windows and proceed directly to Java applications, Android...

Comment: Also, how comfortable do you feel around environments where all TYPES ARE IN CAPS and all szVrwbleNamez are in Hungarian, and everything is prefixed with `_t`? And strings have to be 16-bit encoded.

Comment: Forget about WinAPI. Just use some GUI library (Qt, wxWidgets, ...)

Answer (score 1):

C++ don't have a native library to create GUI.

You need to use some library that supports C++ and Windows.

There are plenty of them - WinAPI, Qt, wxWidgets, SDL, GTK+ and so on.

There are so many articles, even on stackoverflow, which compares them all, etc.

If you want some more windows/dialogs app I would recommend Qt (http://qt-project.org/)

It's

- easy to understand
- very good readable code
- multiplatform
- easy to learn
- very well documented
- big and famous projects are using Qt
- has Qt Creator, Qt Designer and Qt Linguist

And there are so many examples at the Qt web page to start with.

Here is an example of Hello world code

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QLabel win("Hello World!");
    win.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

But if you want to make some one window game I would recommend SDL (http://www.libsdl.org/) and lazyfoo tutorials (http://lazyfoo.net/)